# How to setup OpenCL in Cygwin for Intel GPU

Tags: gcc, gpu, cygwin, opencl, intel

I have a Laptop with `Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 GPU` in it. I added `OpenCL` developer package to `Cygwin`. I have found a small [Mandelbrot-set calculator program](https://github.com/benhiller/opencl-mandelbrot) for `OpenCL` in C on `GitHub`. It is for `Apple`, so I modified the Makefile to use the proper headers and settings for `gcc`. Now the code compiles and executes nicely (bmp file created):

```
$ ./mandelbrot.exe
Device 0: GenuineIntel pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz
```

I have two questions:

#1. How can I add (if it is possible) the Intel GPU to the `/etc/OpenCL/vendors` list? I tried to install from Intel site the `Intel CPU runtime for OpenCL Applications for Windows OS` and `Intel Graphics Technology driver package`, but I do not know where can I find the proper `OpenCL` dll I can point in the `intel.idc` file.

#2. In `/etc/OpenCL/vendors` I have found a `pocl.icd` file pointing to `cygpocl-2.dll`. I assume this is the pthread library. But it seems to me it is running only a single thread, although I have 4 cores. Should I do any modification to run it in multiple threads? I debugged the code and it seems that as there are only one device found, so it runs only on one thread. In the initialization function it sets the `device_work_size` property for processing a stirp per device of the final bmp. But as there is only one device, the whole bmp is processed by one run (one `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` and one `clEnqueueReadBuffer` is called).

**UPDATE**

I have installed [Intel(R) Graphics – Windows* DCH Drivers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19344/intel-graphics-windows-dch-drivers.html). It installed graphics drivers. I have found the intelocl64.dll (as `/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/intel64/intelocl64.dll`). I put this whole path into `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/intel.icd` file. So far, so good. Now it cannot even find pthread device... Bah...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use the GPU from cygwin. I would recommend to either build a native Windows binary (e.g. with Visual Studio or Intel DPC++) or  use WSL. See https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/blob/master/WSL.md for requirements.